# How to check: VC++ redistributable 2010 libraries are installed or not

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++

I am creating setup for our application [myapp.exe] using Visual Studio Setup and Deployment Wizard.
How do I check, if VC++ VCRedist 2010 or higher is installed
if not, then install and continue the setup

Tried:

1. including vcredist_x86.exe in appdata folder and running it through custom steps, it works fine for new setups but it fails, if 2010 or higher libraries are already installed.
2. tried adding registry search condition and adding launch condition, but it is not working
   because, in registry, earlier, it used to be HKLM\Software\Microsoft...\X86\Installed = 1
   but now, it has, HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node...\X86\Installed = 1

and also, in this case, we need to check for each VC2010,vc2012.

Any solution for this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Standard DLL-Hell of course.  A "did somebody else install it yet" check doesn't exactly solve it, you are still running the program with DLLs that you never tested your program with.  Only real fix is to not create DLL Hell in the first place.  Use local deployment.  Copy the DLLs you tested with into the same directory as the exe that uses them.

Comment: First, We have tested and it works with VC++ 10 or higher. Second, VC++ libraries are installed in GAC or some system defined location. Copying in local, at place of myapp.exe won't solve the purpose. Any more ideas?

Comment: You could consider, you know, stop trying to corrupt the user's machine by installing outdated DLLs.